# How to add environment variable from java code

Tags: java, postgresql, environment-variables, processbuilder, pg-upgrade

Want to add "PGPASSWORD" env variable from my java application.

I know using below way, we can add.

private void setPgPasswordEnv(String pwdValue) {

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", "SET");

    Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();

    envMap.put("PGPASSWORD", pwdValue);
}
```

If we add using above, will it persist till my application runs?

Is there any best way to add env variable from java?

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish: you want to make this enviroment variable to be accessible by what other process?

Answer (score 1):

If you do that code, it applies to the new process(es) running the `CMD` program, when you subsequently call `pb.start()`.

It does not affect the running Java program, and it does not affect any other `ProcessBuilder`, since each `ProcessBuilder` has it's own copy of the environment variables to set for the new process(es).

As *fully explained* in the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`environment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment--).